# cocoa:Multiple buttons to set the picture，Tab effect

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

There are several buttons，Click on one of，Change the picture of this button，Other button to set another picture。The following code where there is an error?

```
NSButton *button = (NSButton *)sender;
NSInteger tag = button.tag;
[button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"menuBtnHover.png"]];
for (int i = 5; i <= 8; i++) {
    if (tag != i) {
        button =[(NSButton *)[self contentView] viewWithTag:i];
        [button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"menuBtn.png"]];
    }
}
```

**Add test**，`button` ＝ `null`

```
NSLog(@"button tag: %ld %d %@", tag,i ,button);
```

[image]

Comment: What problem u are facing with your original code ?

Comment: If you use that source code what problem u r facing as it will execute properly. Do you get any error ?

Comment: `[button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"menuBtnHover.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`Friends have suggested this change，But the error

Comment: That will not work because it is for UIButton and you are working for NSButton. Please remove that image and code too. Than again back to your problem. Unable to get your problem exactly.

Comment: Can you add your code how do you create all buttons and add to view ?

Comment: Add interface builder inside , can browse

Comment: did you assigned tag in interface builder to all buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
 NSButton *button = (NSButton *)sender;
NSInteger tag = button.tag;
[button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"menuBtnHover.png"]];
for (int i = 5; i <= 8; i++) {
if (tag != i) { button =[(NSButton *)[self contentView] viewWithTag:i];                

   if(button)[button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"menuBtn.png"]];}
  }
```

Comment: Can not achieve the effect of the tab

Comment: `self.window` .Find a solution`button =[(NSButton *)[self.window contentView] viewWithTag:i]; `